# Rewrite Where condition using Lateral Join

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

I have a `WITH` statement which returns a table like followings:

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | 4 |

The desired output of my query is where `parent_id` is `null` or `parent_id` is present in the `id` column:

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | 4 |

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE parent_id IS NULL OR parent_id = ANY(SELECT id from items)
```

As far I have understood, lateral joins are faster than the `ANY` operator so my idea was to rewrite the above query using them. I started with:

```
SELECT * FROM items i1
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM items i2 WHERE i2.parent_id = i1.id ) t ON true
```

But where do I add the condition to take the items where `parent_id` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM items t1
LEFT JOIN items t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.parent_id IS NULL
OR t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

This is the best performing approach (assuming you have an index on the `id` column, which is almost certainly the case).

Comment: Damn, that was easy, sometimes I overthink...